# Node.js Mongodb documents values type is BSON LONG how to get accurate value?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, bson

I have a mongo client that connect to atlas database and i'm getting a document with `findOne` query and I'm getting a document which his INT64 values is BSON LONG type. when trying to get the original value of it with `toNumber` function im getting a close number to it but not the accurate one which is very bad in my case. 
What can I do in order to get the original accurate value?

`client.db(DATABASE_NAME).collection(SERVERS_COLLECTION).findOne({},{id: server_id});`

server_id is an Integer.

example:
308567034344767488 becomes 308567034344767500

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example of a value that isn't accurate as well as your code that is using the `toNumber` function? The current description isn't entirely clear on the type conversion involved.

Comment: @Stennie updated the question

Comment: `toNumber()` will convert the number to the closest floating-point representation, which isn't able to maintain the full 64-bit integer precision. `toString()` will return the full precision, but as a string. What are you trying to do with the value?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it applies to your case, but I solved a similar issue (my ORM was always converting to BSON LONG type) by storing the field in MongoDB as a string.

Since yours seems to be an ID, I suggest to read also [this discussion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/361395/when-would-you-use-a-long-string-id-instead-of-a-simple-integer) and adapt your design accordingly.